# Remove comma if its the last item in the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove the comma on the item if its the last item on the object.

```
 Object.entries(product.name).map(
            ([key, value]) => {
            return value ? <span>{`${key}, `}</span> : value && key === key.length - 1 ? <span>{key}</span> : null;
            })
```

So basically, if the value of key is true, it will return a comma right beside the key & if its not the last, if its the last it must only return the key without the comma.

How can I achieve this here?

Comment: `if (value) { return ... } else { if (value && key === key.length - 1) { ... } else { return null } }` - The `else { if (...) ... }` part will never be executed because otherwise `value` would have to be falsy and truthy at the same time o.O

Comment: Is there a reason why this is mashed into a ternary operator within a ternary operator?

Comment: ternary operator has made your code hard to read. What do you want to return if the `value` is a falsy value? If you don't return anything, resulting array will contain the value `undefined` at that index.

Comment: Has the `, ` to be _in_ the `<span>...</span>`? Otherwise just grab the keys and `.join()` them with `</span><span>` and add a `<span>` at the start and an `</span>` at the end

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to filter the `true` values from `product.name` object and then simply `join` the array with comma `,`

```
 const products = Object.keys(product.name).filter((key)=>product.name[key]);
 const commaSeperatedProducts = products.join(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the index. If the index is equal to `arr.length - 1` it's the last element in the array.

```
Object.entries(product.name).map(([key, value], index, arr) => {
  if (!value) return;
  return index === arr.length - 1 ? (
    <span>{key}</span>
  ) : (
    <span>{`${key}, `}</span>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the "," from the return in the map, and add join to return it with comma.
i do not have your data structure but something like that should do the work:

```
Object.entries(product.name).map(
   ([key, value]) => {
       return value ? <span>{`${key}`}</span> : value && key === key.length - 1 ? <span>{key}</span> : null;
    }).join(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

`key === key.length - 1 ?`  this condition is incorrect. `key.length -1`  does not return the last Key.
Use `Object.keys(ObjName).length -1` to get the Number of last Key and then Use `Object.keys(ObjName)[keyNumber]` to get the last key.

```
var lastKeyNum = Object.keys(product.name).length -1
Object.entries(product.name).map(
    ([key, value]) => {
    return value ? key === Object.keys(product.name)[lastKeyNum] ? <span>{key}</span>  : <span>{`${key}, `}</span>  : null
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the data structure product looks like, so I've made an assumption and included it with the answer I provided. However, if this assumption is wrong do update me.

In addition, each span you are mapping to [needs a unique ID (key)](https://adhithiravi.medium.com/why-do-i-need-keys-in-react-lists-dbb522188bbb)  so that they are used performantly.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const product = {
  name: {
    hat: "UID-001",
    shoes: "UID-002",
    jacket: "UID-003",
    jeans: "UID-004"
  }
};

const MapExample = () =>
  Object.entries(product.name).map(([key, _], idx, arr) =>
    idx === arr.length - 1 ? <span key={key}>{`${key}`}</span> : <span key={key}>{`${key},`}</span>
  );

ReactDOM.render(<MapExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```